# Need help sending file with Indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy-9

1. I use TIdTCPServer and TIdTCPClient, both client and server are on the same local network with 100 mbps
2. Need to send files upto 2 MB each
3. I have no experiences with Indy and Socket programming

*After the client send request to the server, it then looping until disconnect from the server, the file is created with the client itself but has 0 byte in size

IdTCPServer.OnExecute
...

```
begin
  CS.Enter;

  try
    InputString := AThread.Connection.ReadLn;

    if InputString = 'PIC' then begin
      AFullFileName := FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg';
      if FileExists(AFullFileName) then begin
        AFileStream := TFileStream.Create(AFullFileName, fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyNone);

        AThread.Connection.OpenWriteBuffer;
        AThread.Connection.WriteStream(AFileStream);
        AThread.Connection.CloseWriteBuffer;

        FreeAndNil(AFileStream);
      end;

      AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;

  CS.Leave;
end;
```

Client.OnButtonClick
...

```
begin
  with IdTCPClient do begin
    if Connected then Disconnect;
    Host := '127.0.0.1';
    Port := 2018;
    Connect;
    WriteLn('PIC');
    //different folder with server's folder
    if FileExists(FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg') then
      DeleteFile(FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg');
    AFileStream := TFileStream.Create(FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg', fmCreate);
    while Connected do
      ReadStream(AFileStream, -1, true);
    FreeAndNil(AFileStream);
    Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a classic newbie mistake of mismatching the WriteStream() and ReadStream() calls. By default, WriteStream() DOES NOT send the stream size, but the parameter values you are passing to ReadStream() tell it to expect the stream size.

Other mistakes you are making:

1. You are calling ReadStream() in a loop, but not calling WriteStream() in a loop.
2. Wrapping your entire OnExecute code in a critical section. Don't do that.
3. Wrapping your entire OnExecute code in a try/except that swallows all exceptions. DO NOT swallow EIdException-derived exceptions. TIdTCPServer needs to handle them.
4. Calling ShowMessage(). It is not thread-safe. Use Windows.MessageBox() instead.
5. Using write buffering with WriteStream(). That is a huge waste of memory for large files. Get rid of that.

**Update**: try this:

Server:

```
begin
  InputString := AThread.Connection.ReadLn;
  if InputString = 'PIC' then begin
    AFullFileName := FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg';
    AFileStream := TFileStream.Create(AFullFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      AThread.Connection.WriteStream(AFileStream, True, True);
    finally
      AFileStream.Free;
    end;
  end;
  AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
end;
```

Client:

```
begin
  if IdTCPClient.Connected then IdTCPClient.Disconnect;
  IdTCPClient.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  IdTCPClient.Port := 2018;
  if FileExists(FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg') then
    DeleteFile(FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg');
  AFileStream := TFileStream.Create(FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg', fmCreate);
  try
    try
      IdTCPClient.Connect;
      try
        IdTCPClient.WriteLn('PIC');
        IdTCPClient.ReadStream(AFileStream, -1, False);
      finally
        IdTCPClient.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      AFileStream.Free;
    end;
  except
    DeleteFile(FFilePath + 'PIC01.jpg');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: More questions, I actually started by copying Indy's example code, according to your advices, when ReadStream() should be in loop???

Comment: Don't I need critical section???, what is it actually? :(

Comment: All methods within OnExecute should be thread-safe right?, including accessing the VCL.

Comment: I don't get the picture yet about sending "Stream" over the socket, calling WriteStream() once meaning there is a one single packet or what?, is there a limit size of the stream?  If I was about the send large file for 100 MB, I still need to call WriteStream() once, or what's coding going to be?

Comment: `OnExecute` is triggeed in a worker thread, so any code you write in it must be thread-safe. That does **NOT** mean wrapping the entire code in a critical section. That just serializes your code and restricts the advantage of using threads at all. You only need to serialize code that actually needs to be protected from concurrent access, like UI accesses. As for `WriteStream()`, it sends however many TCP packets it requires to send the stream. It has parameters to tell it whether to send the entire stream or just from the current Position, whether to send the size before the actual data, etc.

Comment: `ReadStream()` has corresponding parameters. If you tell `WriteStream()` to send the stream size before sending the stream data, you can tell `ReadStream()` to read the size before reading the data, etc. `ReadStream()` reads as many TCP packets as it needs to until the stream is finished. It just happens that the **default** parameter values of `WriteStream()` and `ReadStream()` are not mirrors of each other, which you have to take into account when using them together. You only need to call `WriteStream()` and `ReadStream()` once per stream.

Comment: Indy 9 only supports 32-bit streams, so reads/writes are limited to 2 GB max.  Indy 10 supports 64-bit streams (if you want to send the stream size before the stream data, you need to set the `LargeStream` parameter to True so the size is sent/received using a 64-bit integer and not a 32-bit integer).

Comment: I think, I get the big picture now, thanks. More questions, wrapping part of the code in critical section meaning serializing that code???  Did you mean I only need to wrap part of the code where I access UI, VCL ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31155/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-kongthap)